How to prove that if $\int_{-1}^1 √(1-x^2)f(x) \ dx= \ 0$ for some nonnegtive continuous function $f(x)$, then $f(x)=0$ on $[-1,1]$
How to prove that if $$\int_{-1}^1 √(1-x^2)f(x)  \ dx= \ 0$$ for some nonnegtive continuous function $f(x)$, then $f(x)=0$ on $[-1,1]$
Does anyone have any idea about this question? I try to use contrapositive but still don't get many insights.



If $g:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is non-negative and continuous and $\int_{-1}^1 g(x)dx=0$, then $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$.


Apply 1. to $g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}f(x)$ to deduce that $\sqrt{1-x^2}f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$. For $-1<x<1$, divide by $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to deduce that $f(x)=0$.


Since $f$ is continuous, $f(-1)=f(1)=0$.



Thank you so much! I think I get it.
